# Nodejs - make requests wait on lazy init of an object

Tags: node.js

let's say I have an application that returns exchange rates for today. 
The service should read data via REST then save in cache and give clients from this cache. I want this request to 3rd party API to happen upon first attempt to get today's rate (kind of lazy init for every day).

Something like this:
 (1) HTTP Request to get rate (form my app's client) 
 (2) if rate for today is available then return it
 else
     (3) read it from 3rd party service (via REST request)
     (4) save in cache
     (5) return from cache

The whole logic is written by mean of promises but the is a problem if i have millions of requests simultaneously at the very beginning of the day. In this case if one of the requests is on operations (3), (4) or (5) ( which are organized as a promise chain) operation (1) and (2) for other request can be handled by node in between.
E.g. while first requests is still waiting for the 3rd party API to response and the cache is empty other million of requests can also fire the same request to the same 3rd party API.

My thought is to chain operation (3) to some kind of an object A with the promise ( A.promise) inside that exposes resolve function to A. All other requests would wait (not synchronously wait of course) till the first request updates the cache and calls A.resolve() which will resolve A.promise.

But it looks a bit ugly, any idea of a better approach?

**Update**

I've got one solution, not sure whether it's node.js style:

```
function Deferred(){;
    this.promise = false

    this.markInProgress = ()=>{
        this.promise =  new Promise((res, rej)=>{
            this.resolve = res;
            this.reject = rej;
        })
    }

    this.markDone = ()=>{
        this.resolve()
        this.promise = false
    }

    this.isInProgress = this.promise
}

let state = new Deferred();

function updateCurrencyRate(){
return db.any(`select name from t_currency group by name`)
    .then((currencies) => {
        return getRateFromCbr()
            .then(res => Promise.all(
                 currencies.map((currency, i, currencies) =>
                    saveCurrency(
                        currency.name, 
                        parseRate(res, currency.name)))));
     })
}


function loadCurrencyRateFroDate(date){
    if (state.isInProgress){
        return state.promise
    } else {
        state.markInProgress();
        return updateCurrencyRate()
            .then(()=> {
                state.markDone();
            })
    }
}

function getCurrencyRateForDate(date){
    return getCurrencytRateFromDb(date)
        .then((rate) => {
            if (rate[0]) {
                return Promise.resolve(rate)
            } else {               
                loadCurrencyRateFroDate(date)
                    .then(()=>getCurrencytRateFromDb(date))
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: Hit the third party API on an interval instead of lazily. Then the problem goes away. If the cache gets stale (e.g. because the other service went down) then return a 503.

Comment: 503 is not an option. It should always return proper numbers. Frankly speaking there are solutions that don't involve this complexity, e.g. return something like yesterday's rates in case if cache is empty but as I'm a bit new to node and lazy init seems to be a standard problem I thought that there is probably some standard solution to it.

Comment: You know your problem domain better than us, if stale data is ok then return stale data. But if you're expecting millions of hits possibly within seconds of the server starting up then lazily fetching the data is unnecessary, and if the service should always return proper numbers then there's no point in even starting the server until you have the 3rd party data. Lazy initializing is for stuff you might not need, not stuff that's critical.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a very simple *queue, flush and fallback* approach to this.

- Implement a queuing mechanism (maybe with RabbitMQ) and route all your requests to the queue. This way you can hold off responding to requests when cache expires.
- Create an expirable cache layer (maybe a redis cache) and expire your cache everyday.
- By default route your requests from the queue to get data from cache. On receiving the data from cache, if the cache has expired, hold the queue and get data directly from 3rd party and update your cache and its expiry.
- flush your cache every day

With queues, you have better control over the traffic. You can also add 3rd party API call as a fallback way to get data when your cache fails or anything goes wrong.

Comment: The issue is still there: I can have millions of requests doing the same things one by one:  "On receiving the data from cache, if the cache has expired, hold the queue and get data directly from 3rd party and update your cache and its expiry."
Cause checking the cache and saving into it results that I've got from 3rd party are 2 operations chained by mean of promises so there is not guarantee they will be executed one by one.